# what is the Time zone used for signedDateTime field in get Envelope rest api response

Tags: docusignapi

I have enabled the checkbox 'Allow users to set their own Time Zone and Date Format' under admin Regional Settings
I have selected different time zones under Regional Settings for DocuSign sender, DocuSign viewer and DocuSign admin account settings.
.
I have created one envelope and used 3 users . one  DocuSign sender , one DocuSign viewer and one non DocuSign user. 3 signers got signed.
when I have tried to invoke the below rest api and included optional query parameter include=recipients

/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}

signedDateTime field for all 3 users in the response shows the same time zone and that time zone is different from all the users settings.
is signedDateTime field shows unique timezone irrespective of users timezone?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The timezone is an account settings and the sender's timezone is reflected in the envelope PDF. However, when you look at meta-data your own timezone can be used. The completed document cannot be different/modified for each user based on their timezone, since it's a document and there's only one version of that document, but meta-data in features like "history" and other places where you see information about the envelope will be done in the uers' selected timezone.
Hope this makse sense.

Comment: signedDateTime field is not shown in users time(neither sender nor viewer) in the above mentioned rest api response right. so, what time zone  it is taking to  show the datetime in the response.  I observed all the date fields shown in UTC only.  I assume This Timezone is same for all dosucisgn enevlopes.

Comment: UTC is used as a default when no time zone is set by the user.